# Why is it "der Presse" instead of "die Presse"

Tags: noun, definite-article

> Der Presse zufolge war der Prozess unfair.

Found this sentence while learning. The translation is: *The press said the trial was unfair.*
Since *Presse* is feminine, why is it preceded by *der*?

Comment: The translation is "According to the press, the trial was unfair".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*zufolge* is a postposition which can be translated as *according to* and whose object (here, *Presse)* is in the dative case, and the dative of *die Presse* is *der Presse. der Presse zufolge* therefore translates to *according to the press* and your whole example sentence translates to:

> According to the press, the trial was unfair.

The translation you gave is a rather free one, which may change the emphasis and nuances in some contexts.

Note that *zufolge* can also be used as a preposition taking the *genetive* case, which is however unusual.

Answer (score 6):

The reason is the preposition `zufolge`: it requires the dative. The dative of `die Presse` is `der Presse`.

Refer to:
[Link](http://canoonet.eu/inflection/presse:N:F)

It becomes more apparent when rephrasing the sentence:

> Zufolge der Presse war der Prozess unfair.

This usage, however, is very unusual. Unlike most prepositions `zufolge` is put after the object it is referring to instead of in front.